# Why isn't my function not working this button element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Nothing seems to be working on my button element. Here I have more than one function to test if it gives the alert window-- they don't work but it seems like its correctly written. I will provide 2 function codes which either don't work and the html button element being targeted to help inspect the code. I am 1 month into javascript so I apologize in advance if the mistake in here turns out to be a silly mistake.

HTML button element:

```
<form input='text' action="" method="post" name="entry" class="journalentry" id='form'>
    <textarea name='entrybody' rows='12' cols='90' placeholder="Anything you want to write about the day you are thinking of." class="journalentry"></textarea
    <button type='submit' onclick= "test()" id='submitid' class='submitbutton'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

function #1 (creating the element from javascript and adding an event listener. this one doesnt use the html form but function #2 does):

```
var submitelement = document.createElement('BUTTON');
var submittextnode = document.createTextNode("SUBMIT ME");
submitelement.appendChild(submittextnode);
document.body.appendChild(submitelement);
var submitattr = document.createAttribute("id");
submitAttr.value = "submitbutton";
submitelement.setAttributeNode("submitAttr");


submitelement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('88888');
})
```

function #2 (commented out function #1 and wrote this code out. still doesn't work) :

```
document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", test();
function test () {
    var url = 'http://news.google.com';
    var method = "GET";
    var httpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpObj.open(method, url, 'true');
        httpObj.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
}

function processRequest (e) {
    if (httpObj.readyState == 4 && httpObj.status == 200)) {
        // time to partay!!!
        var response = httpObj.responseText;
        alert(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: you're missing a `)` in  `document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", test();
` Sometimes it really helps to open console and read your errors.

Comment: document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", test());

Answer (score 2):

Function is not triggering that means you've made some blunders in your coding (syntax error). 

**Try Correcting Following Issues:-**
1.Replace this line `document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", test();` with this one `document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", test());` 
2. Shift this line `document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", test())`;
before closing your `<script> tag`(at the end).

**How to debug javascript program?** 
You can easily debug it by going right clicking on main window screen-> a drop down will appear select inspect element option a window will appear -> click console on tabs. Here you can see your javascript errors red highlighted.